# python: dynamically create and execute existing variable names

Tags: python

I need to create a ORDERED list that contains a series of sub-lists. But I'm not sure how to iterate through known variables.

Here's an example. Let's say I have the following sub-lists:

```
list_0 = [0, 1, 2]
list_1 = [3, 4, 5, 6]
list_2 = [7, 8, 9]
```

I'm trying to append the lists to a larger list `list_all`:

```
list_all = [ [0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9] ]
```

So I'm trying to iterate through the variable names but I'm not sure this is possible?

```
list_all = [list_{num}.format(num=i) for i in range(3)]
# SyntaxError
```

This seems to work if `list_all` contains strings of the known variables but I don't need the variables obviously, I need the data within those variables.

```
list_all = ['list_{num}'.format(num=i) for i in range(3)]
print list_all
# ['list_0', 'list_1', 'list_2']
```

So I guess the question is how can I dynamically create and execute python variable names? I need to do this because the number of lists changes with each use case.

Comment: What you should do is use a list (or other data structure) instead of naming your variables "foo_#".  Then you can very simply and naturally iterate through your list to do what you want.

Comment: don't create variables `list_0`, `list_1` but list or dictionary `list[0]`, `list[1]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really, *really* need this, you could get the variables and their values from the [`globals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) or [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) dictionaries.

```
>>> list_0 = [0, 1, 2]
>>> list_1 = [3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> list_2 = [7, 8, 9]
>>> [globals()["list_{}".format(i)] for i in range(3)]
[[0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

However, almost certainly it would be a better idea to store the individual lists as part of `list_all` to begin with, and access them as `list_all[0]` etc. instead of `list_0`:

```
>>> list_all = []
>>> list_all.append([0, 1, 2])
>>> list_all.append([3, 4, 5, 6])
>>> list_all.append([7, 8, 9])
>>> list_all[0]
[0, 1, 2]
```

Comment: Great answer thanks! I also figured out `eval()` works in this case too